# Kill Linux of Chromebook installed via Linux

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, chromebook, google-chrome-os, kill

Some aplications I need (like VLC player, Office, etc) I instaled via linux beta on my Chromebooks. It works fine most of the time but when one of those processes crashes I can't kill it or restart it quickly. So far only shuting down the entire Chromebook system solves the problem (But it is really annoying have to restart and wait long minutes). Example: I often use VLC to show some subtitled .mkv movies during my classes and often the application freezes/crashes. The icon of VLC still appear on the taskbar but do not respond (circle/running - see image below) and I am not able to open another (or the same) video.
[image: Icon of VLC during unresponding phase]

I found no answer for this question on StackExchange sites and those searches listed below also don't solve the problem:

[Shut Down Linux (BETA) - DOES NOT SOLVE THE PROBLEM](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/12344626/how-can-i-kill-a-chrome-os-linux-app-that-seems-to-have-crashed-i-had-to-power-off-the-chromebook?hl=en)

[Kill linux beta process on linux terminal - DO NOT WORK BECAUSE THE SPECIFIC PROCESS IS NOT LISTED via PS/PID](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/j9vut8/how_to_kill_a_linux_program_running_on_a/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
See image below: [image: Kill vlc]

[Force close app via Chromebook task manager - DO NOT SOLVE because the process is not listed](https://www.howtogeek.com/414136/how-to-close-unresponsive-chromebook-apps/)

Comment: Well, it is `kill -9 <PID>`, not `kil -9 <PID>`, and that PID, 1001, is of the grep command, which has finished running. That process list seems exceedingly short.

Comment: OK, but which is the PID of the VLC process?? Since I did not restart my device the aplicantion is still not responding - almost ten ours past :0 .
I don't Know what to do, how to kill the process...

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

1. Right-Click 'Terminal'. (That is the command line app).
2. Then, click ''Shut Down Linux (Beta).

Comment: doesnt work as I mentioned on the thread  :(